# BadSessionNotActivated,0x80270000,The session cannot be used because ActivateSession has not been called

Tags: opc-ua, node-opcua

Whenever I try to send an ActivateSessionRequest to the opcua server, it throws an error stating "**BadSessionNotActivated**". Below is the message format of ActivateSessionRequest:

```
  var ActivateSessionRequest v_activateSessionReq := {
  requestHeader := session_reqHeader,

  clientSignature := {
    algorithm := valueof(tr_String("http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None")),
    Signature := valueof(tr_ByteString({48, 130, 4, 19, 48, 130, 2, 251, 160, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 16, 26, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, 134, 72, 134, 247, 13, 1, 1, 11, 5, 0, 48, 40, 49, 18, 48, 16, 6, 3, 85, 4, 10, 19, 9, 78, 111, 100, 101, 79, 80, 67, 85, 65, 49, 18, 48, 16, 6, 3, 85, 4, 3, 19, 9, 78, 111, 100, 101, 79, 80, 67, 85, 65, 48, 34, 24, 15, 50, 48, 49, 56, 48, 50, 48, 53, 49, 51, 53, 54, 48, 50, 90, 24, 15, 50, 48, 49, 57, 48, 50, 48, 53, 49, 51, 53, 54, 48, 50, 90, 48, 40, 49, 18, 48, 16, 6, 3, 85, 4, 10, 19, 9, 78, 111, 100, 101, 79, 80, 67, 85, 65, 49, 18, 48, 16, 6, 3, 85, 4, 3, 19, 9, 78, 111, 100, 101, 79, 80, 67, 85, 65, 48, 130, 1, 34, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, 134, 72, 134, 247, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 3, 130, 1, 15, 0, 48, 130, 1, 10, 2, 130, 1, 1, 0, 178, 243, 137, 233, 196, 81, 105, 65, 195, 121, 2, 212, 193, 216, 187, 73, 213, 135, 135, 163, 140, 13, 165, 74, 203, 63, 212, 221, 158, 178, 59, 89, 71, 118, 141, 147, 102, 111, 5, 111, 52, 36, 160, 187, 189, 244, 38, 0, 200, 206, 33, 174, 227, 110, 132, 79, 202, 59, 223, 29, 116, 217, 12, 193, 191, 44, 87, 168, 113, 69, 125, 23, 239, 71, 139, 38, 121, 203, 255, 54, 196, 68, 199, 249, 43, 206, 32, 255, 192, 10, 134, 200, 71, 104, 150, 176, 66, 233, 241, 17, 227, 3, 96, 172, 169, 164, 96, 113, 114, 190, 194, 28, 232, 161, 46, 241, 170, 0, 70, 215, 89, 228, 130, 219, 152, 216, 85, 234, 72, 142, 103, 63, 211, 101, 238, 224, 160, 84, 134, 171, 241, 148, 60, 212, 190, 250, 16, 203, 248, 212, 153, 16, 56, 159, 153, 185, 202, 239, 135, 150, 185, 188, 80, 207, 62, 122, 172, 25, 110, 80, 124, 166, 227, 86, 32, 97, 137, 35, 164, 156, 1, 150, 51, 64, 140, 180, 196, 162, 32, 131, 207, 170, 144, 19, 90, 251, 239, 173, 33, 65, 135, 125, 110, 137, 2, 184, 106, 146, 55, 166, 217, 141, 127, 163, 137, 57, 91, 158, 133, 29, 218, 205, 174, 98, 208, 123, 30, 240, 42, 29, 102, 187, 113, 26, 166, 30, 55, 207, 49, 32, 132, 173, 115, 155, 7, 207, 206, 201, 27, 209, 52, 198, 119, 210, 142, 161, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 163, 130, 1, 65, 48, 130, 1, 61, 48, 12, 6, 3, 85, 29, 19, 1, 1, 255, 4, 2, 48, 0, 48, 29, 6, 3, 85, 29, 14, 4, 22, 4, 20, 162, 197, 27, 92, 111, 157, 37, 181, 146, 213, 162, 250, 174, 112, 194, 229, 164, 3, 176, 205, 48, 81, 6, 3, 85, 29, 35, 4, 74, 48, 72, 128, 20, 162, 197, 27, 92, 111, 157, 37, 181, 146, 213, 162, 250, 174, 112, 194, 229, 164, 3, 176, 205, 161, 44, 164, 42, 48, 40, 49, 18, 48, 16, 6, 3, 85, 4, 10, 19, 9, 78, 111, 100, 101, 79, 80, 67, 85, 65, 49, 18, 48, 16, 6, 3, 85, 4, 3, 19, 9, 78, 111, 100, 101, 79, 80, 67, 85, 65, 130, 2, 16, 26, 48, 91, 6, 3, 85, 29, 17, 4, 84, 48, 82, 134, 44, 117, 114, 110, 58, 97, 118, 100, 111, 111, 116, 99, 104, 97, 108, 107, 101, 45, 86, 105, 114, 116, 117, 97, 108, 66, 111, 120, 58, 78, 111, 100, 101, 79, 80, 67, 85, 65, 45, 83, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114, 130, 9, 108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 104, 111, 115, 116, 130, 23, 97, 118, 100, 111, 111, 116, 99, 104, 97, 108, 107, 101, 45, 86, 105, 114, 116, 117, 97, 108, 66, 111, 120, 48, 44, 6, 9, 96, 134, 72, 1, 134, 248, 66, 1, 13, 4, 31, 22, 29, 79, 112, 101, 110, 83, 83, 76, 32, 71, 101, 110, 101, 114, 97, 116, 101, 100, 32, 67, 101, 114, 116, 105, 102, 105, 99, 97, 116, 101, 48, 14, 6, 3, 85, 29, 15, 1, 1, 255, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 252, 48, 32, 6, 3, 85, 29, 37, 1, 1, 255, 4, 22, 48, 20, 6, 8, 43, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 1, 6, 8, 43, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 2, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, 134, 72, 134, 247, 13, 1, 1, 11, 5, 0, 3, 130, 1, 1, 0, 147, 168, 16, 170, 204, 221, 81, 100, 167, 38, 104, 142, 27, 107, 108, 87, 94, 195, 100, 124, 141, 117, 46, 23, 231, 145, 68, 182, 241, 225, 148, 94, 144, 1, 142, 61, 228, 88, 64, 243, 126, 180, 17, 33, 164, 128, 234, 183, 198, 31, 223, 59, 125, 218, 110, 0, 112, 182, 244, 199, 220, 139, 114, 162, 153, 76, 245, 134, 167, 163, 199, 175, 153, 82, 214, 106, 142, 15, 52, 87, 11, 230, 95, 75, 23, 170, 137, 92, 144, 76, 111, 179, 1, 36, 150, 191, 84, 226, 252, 199, 228, 38, 97, 138, 26, 32, 230, 65, 110, 154, 179, 104, 146, 186, 104, 248, 246, 26, 136, 12, 15, 220, 6, 203, 220, 141, 230, 11, 185, 247, 250, 9, 76, 236, 74, 101, 149, 32, 100, 220, 249, 46, 255, 129, 21, 126, 6, 86, 230, 198, 94, 228, 51, 50, 73, 103, 57, 212, 105, 255, 9, 181, 189, 104, 121, 27, 21, 78, 196, 226, 99, 176, 44, 194, 176, 211, 216, 13, 81, 142, 35, 52, 76, 116, 49, 190, 253, 199, 166, 51, 41, 105, 81, 90, 222, 232, 223, 74, 100, 203, 192, 130, 48, 46, 116, 37, 236, 199, 70, 81, 60, 244, 6, 45, 51, 246, 4, 254, 178, 240, 14, 22, 64, 200, 134, 199, 249, 171, 118, 219, 81, 124, 218, 91, 175, 65, 59, 233, 19, 110, 217, 72, 165, 91, 75, 182, 12, 214, 215, 30, 169, 153, 36, 7, 69, 60  ,224, 153, 75, 106, 120, 118, 227, 63, 4, 63, 14, 101, 116, 161, 229, 230, 127, 196, 14, 37, 23, 251, 174, 94, 204, 114, 180, 26, 77, 200, 61, 148}))         
    },

  clientSoftwareCertificates := { realArray := { arrayLength := 0, arrayValues := { } } },

  localeIds := valueof(tr_ListOfLocaleId({})),

  userIdentityToken := {
    encodingByte := 1,
    twoByteNodeValue := omit,
    namespaceIndex := 0,
    fourByteNodeValue := 321,
    encoding := 1,
    parameterLength := 13,
    extensibleParameterBody := {
      anonymousIdentityToken := {
        policyId := valueof(tr_String( "username_basic256"))
      }
    }
  },

  userTokenSignature := {
    algorithm := valueof(tr_StringNull),
    Signature := valueof(tr_ByteStringNull)
  }
}
```

[Client-Server Communication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8SRu.png)
  As shown in the image, ActivateSessionRequest is successful by sending SessionId and AuthenticationToken to the server. The header of ActivateSessionRequest contains AuthenticationToken. But How shall I provide the SessionId to the server? Is it because I am not providing the SessionId in the ActivateSessionRequest that the server throws an error or due to some other mistake? can someone guide me?

Any feedback is highly appreciated. Thank you in Advance

With Regards,

Avdoot

Comment: Do you send a CreateSessionRequest prior to the ActivateSessionRequest ? The Server shall provides the SessionId in the CreateSessionResponse when it is successful.

Comment: Yes.. CreateSessionResponse provides me with SessionId. But, How shall I provide the SessionId to the server?

Comment: Once you got the SessionId with the CreateSessionResponse you shall send other OPC UA Service Requests (ActivateSession, Read, Write,...) with this SessionId in each RequestHeader in the AuthenticationToken field

Comment: Thanz Camille! Your feedback was very helpful. It worked.